# Change page title when div is :target

Tags: html, css, title

I'm working on a one single page navigation system; Is there is a way to change the `<title>` of a page when a div is `:target` (#divname in url)?

EDIT: Yeah, sorry, a Jquery/javascript solution works as well.

Comment: did you try the solution I provided?

Answer (score 1):

If the url contains `#somePage`, use `#somePage` as a selector and retrieve it's `data-title` value.

Then set `<title></title>` as that value. `location.hash` produces `#somePage`

```
$('a').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    if(location.hash) {

        var newPageTitle = $(location.hash).data('title');

        $('title').text(newPageTitle);

    }

});
```

Add a data attribute to your `div` and set it's value to what the page title should be when that link is clicked.

```
<a href="#somePage">Some Page</a>

<div id="somePage" data-title="This Is The Page Title"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in following way:

Assume that you have this html element:

```
<a onclick="onClick1()" href="#test">
    link
</a>
```

and you have this scripts:

```
<script>
function onClick1(){
    setTimeout(onClick,100);
}

function onClick(){
    alert(1);
    if(document.URL.indexOf("#test")>=0){
      document.title = "Your title";
    }
}
</script>
```

then you'll get on click what you need.
Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4ufbk9wx/2/).

Comment: Seems only to work when I refresh the page, and not automatic when I click on a link. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'd add this within a click event and set `"#divname"` dynamically.